# Private resources in a Play application

Tags: playframework

I have a couple of resource files I need to ship with my Play 2.8 application (Scala), but I want them to be baked into the distribution JAR file, not added to the `conf/` directory. The standard sbt directory structure provides for such a use case, but Play overrides that. It's convenient to have the `conf/` directory for user facing config files, no doubt, but I absolutely cannot ship with my proprietary resource files in it. I realize that I can repackage the build, but that seems a hack.

Comment: does `dist` directory not serve your purpose? - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Deploying#Including-additional-files-in-your-distribution

Comment: Please also note that anyone with access to the jar file may extract it like a regular ZIP file, so if you have any secrets there you should use some kind of obfuscator.

Comment: My customers are precluded from looking in the jar by my license agreement. But not in the `conf/` directory. Obfuscation isn't bullet proof, if someone is determined -- that's not my goal. What IS my goal is to exclude the possibility of someone stumbling into them accidentally or by curiosity that is within their legal rights.